# How to programmatically find location of php.ini file?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, grep

Per subject, how do I find location of php.ini file programmatically ?

So far, I am able to use below command to find out if PHP5 has been loaded-

```
 ps x | grep -i apache2 | xargs lsof -p | grep libphp5.so
```

Is there a way I can find out which all files are being used by this shared library (as opposed to a process?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP 5.2.4 you can use [php_ini_loaded_file](http://php.net/manual/de/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php) to retrieve the ini file within PHP. Maybe you can call a simple php script that returns that.
Something like that:

```
fab@jule:/tmp$ cat `php t.php` | grep memory_limit
memory_limit = -1
```

Content t.php:

```
<?php

echo php_ini_loaded_file();

?>
```

Comment: That will only show the contents of the cli version of the file, but the op is asking for the php.ini loaded by libphp5.so via Apache.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for all opened files for a process:

```
lsof -p PID
```

or

```
ls -l /proc/YourPID/fd/
```

then maybe you could do a grep php.ini on the result of opened file list.

Comment: That is what I've been trying but interestingly, php.ini is not being listed by apache2 process at all! btw, I am running php as module in apache2